# graphite error "'ParseResults' object has no attribute 'raw'" when call /render

Tags: grafana, graphite

I installed graphite ( whisper - carbon - graphite-web ) with the pip method.

I connect it to my puppetserver instance ( need graphite to have jrubies informations ).

But when i try to export the data from graphite to my grafana I have an error: [AttributeError: ParseResults object has no attribute raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7PmK.png) when I add the datasource.

And on the graphite-web logfile I have:

```
2021-11-08,16:11:04.396 :: Exception encountered in <POST http://localhost:9091/render>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/errors.py", line 101, in new_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/views.py", line 130, in renderView
    data.extend(evaluateTarget(requestContext, targets))
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 18, in evaluateTarget
    pathExpressions = extractPathExpressions(requestContext, targets)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 205, in extractPathExpressions
    target = grammar.parseString(target)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/grammar.py", line 12, in parseString
    return _grammar.parseString(instring)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 1097, in parse_string
    loc, tokens = self._parse(instring, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 5094, in parseImpl
    return super().parseImpl(instring, loc, doActions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4265, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 5094, in parseImpl
    return super().parseImpl(instring, loc, doActions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4265, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4265, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 3781, in parseImpl
    instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4017, in parseImpl
    instring, loc, doActions,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 824, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn(instring, tokensStart, retTokens)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 282, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit:])
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/grammar_unsafe.py", line 83, in setRaw
    toks[0].raw = s[toks[0].start:toks[0].end]
AttributeError: 'ParseResults' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

Is anyone could help me to understand why I have this error and how fix it ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1  Got the same exact error today on a new Graphite installation ... otherwise exploring the metrics and retrieving data seem to be working properly.

```
2021-11-10,18:31:03.882 :: Exception encountered in <POST https://10.224.115.43:3001/render>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/errors.py", line 101, in new_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/views.py", line 129, in renderView
    data.extend(evaluateTarget(requestContext, targets))
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 18, in evaluateTarget
    pathExpressions = extractPathExpressions(requestContext, targets)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 205, in extractPathExpressions
    target = grammar.parseString(target)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/grammar.py", line 12, in parseString
    return _grammar.parseString(instring)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 1097, in parse_string
    loc, tokens = self._parse(instring, 0)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 5098, in parseImpl
    return super().parseImpl(instring, loc, doActions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4267, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 5098, in parseImpl
    return super().parseImpl(instring, loc, doActions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4267, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4267, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 3780, in parseImpl
    loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse(
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 787, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 4016, in parseImpl
    return e._parse(
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 824, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn(instring, tokensStart, retTokens)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 282, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit:])
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/grammar_unsafe.py", line 83, in setRaw
    toks[0].raw = s[toks[0].start:toks[0].end]
AttributeError: 'ParseResults' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

UPDATE: reinstalling pyparsing with version 2.4.7 (the one I have in another working environment) instead of 3.0.4 (the one presenting the error) seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just try to reinstall pyparsing in version 2.4.7 too and it resolve the problem, i will check if an issue has been created on pyparsing for that problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today as well. Graphite was displaying standard data just fine but I couldn't run any functions against the data (averageSeries, sumSeries, etc).  These requests would all result in an error 500 in the browser with the same stack you've posted above.  The [release notes](https://pyup.io/changelogs/pyparsing/#3.0.4) for pyparsing==3.0.4 describe this as intended behavior:

> result = Word(alphas).parseString("abc")
> result.xyz = 100
>
> now raises this Python exception:
>
> AttributeError: 'ParseResults' object has no attribute 'xyz'
>
> To add new attribute values to ParseResults object in 3.0.0 and later, you must
> assign them using indexed notation:
>
> result["xyz"] = 100

And if you check the referenced line in your stack (grammar_unsafe.py line 83) you'll see that Graphite is indeed attempting to assign the 'raw' attribute without using the indexed notation.  I attempted to edit this line with varying results.  Some graphs would render but there were other issues with apache restart, so simply updating the notation used in setting toks[0].raw only complicates the issue.  I've logged an issue with graphite-web and in the interim, have downgraded my pyparsing to 2.4.7 as suggested in the recommended answer.

Comment: Update: issue submitted with graphite-web [here](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/2726)